# Django ORM query with exclude not working properly

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

I have below Django ORM query which excluding product having 0(zero) sale_price.

```
selected_attr_values = ProductAttribValue.objects.filter(
    product__status_id=1,
    product_id__in=product_attributes_values.values_list('product_id', flat=True).distinct()
).exclude(
    product__sale_price = 0,
    ifield_value = '',
    field_value__isnull=False
).distinct(
    "field_value",
    'field_id'
).values(
    'field_value',
    'product_id',
    'field__caption',
    'field_id',
    'id'
)
```

Above query does not excluding products having 0 sale_price.

But after updating query like below.

```
selected_attr_values = ProductAttribValue.objects.filter(
    product__status_id=1,
    product_id__in=product_attributes_values.values_list('product_id', flat=True).distinct()
).exclude(
    field_value='',
    field_value__isnull=False
).distinct(
    "field_value",
    'field_id'
).exclude(
    product__sale_price=0
).values(
    'field_value',
    'product_id',
    'field__caption',
    'field_id',
    'id'
)
```

it working fine.

So my question is why do I need to call exclude 2 times to get desired output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django by default join multiple conditions with AND operator. Your query will only exclude rows with `product__sale_price=0` AND `field_value=''` AND `field_value__isnull=False`. If you want OR operator between your conditions, you have to use `Q`.

```
from django.db.models import Q


...exclude(Q(product__sale_price=0) | Q(field_value='') | Q(field_value__isnull=False))
```